# Swift UNNotificationRequest identifier of action button tapped local notification

Tags: swift, notifications, identifier, unnotificationrequest

Is it possible to get the UNNotificationRequest identifier of a tapped local notification button or any other information about the notification? Maybe via a delegate?

Thankyou

Comment: Please read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/handling_notifications_and_notification-related_actions

Answer (score 0):

The identifier of the notification is obtained like so:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        let identifier = response.notification.request.identifier
        
        switch response.actionIdentifier {
        
        case "snoozeAction":
            
            print ("Snooze Tapped - identifier :", identifier)
            
            nc.post(name: Notification.Name("didTapSnooze"), object: nil)
            
            
        default:
            break
        }
        
        completionHandler()
        
    }
```